# Does AlmaLinux use both `ifcfg-` and `nmconnection` locations for storing network configuration?

Tags: system-installation, network-interface, networkmanager, alma-linux

I'm working on a system where we rename some of the network interfaces for consistency in the application. We're struggling to configure the IP addresses during the installation. I did a bit of testing, by configuring connections with `nmtui` and it seems as though there are two use cases:

**Automatically named interface:**
When the interface name has the OS-designated name (example `eno1`), the connection configuration is stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eno1.nmconnection`

**Renamed interface:**
When the interface name has been changed (example `data` by providing a `DEVICE` in the `ifcfg-` file), the connection configuration is stored in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-data` file.

Now in both cases, an `ifcfg-` file existed. In the case of `eno1`, the file sets the `MTU` and `ZONE`, in the case of `data`, it sets `NAME` and `DEVICE`.

Does anyone have an explanation, on why the apparent inconsistency and how I should pre-configure my interfaces given the two cases?

**Update:**
I've done some further testing, and regardless of whether or not in include the `NAME` setting in `ifcfg`, as long as the `device` is set to something other than the default, NetworkManager will store the IP configuration for that interface in `ifcfg`. If you populate `NAME` and `DEVICE` with the original interface name, it will store the IP configuration in an `.nmconnection` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to pre-configure my renamed interfaces effectively, so the procedure we're using now is as follows:

1. Do not configure the interfaces with the ks `network` command. This results in network configurations being configured against the default interface name in nmconnection key file format. You can do this if you need the interface during installation. We'll delete them later anyway.
2. In the kickstart `%post` script:

   1. In the new file system (it should be mounted on `/mnt/sysimage`), create the `ifcfg-` files for the interfaces you want to rename. Include `HWADDR` with the MAC address of the interface `DEVICE` with the device name you want and `NAME` with the connection name you want.
   2. Create a `network-config.sh` script that will be run during the first boot that does the following:

      1. Deletes any automatically generated connections in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`
      2. reloads network configurations (`nmcli conn reload`)
      3. uses nmcli to configure your network interfaces using the new device names
      4. disables then re-enables the interfaces
      5. Modifies your boot script to make sure the `network-config.sh` script is only run on the very first boot.

The end result is that renamed interfaces will have their IP configurations stored in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` and your interfaces with default names will be configured in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection`